# Avoiding multiple api calls when same component is rendered multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I made a react dropdown component using hooks. In useEffect hook i call an api to get all the options. How can i avoid multiple api calls when dropdown is called multiple times in list. The code structure is

```
const Dropdown = ({ handleChange }) => {
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
//api call and setOptions
}, []);

return (
<Form.Dropdown name="abcd" label="abcd" options={options} onChange={handleChange} />
);
};

export default Dropdown;
```

I am familiar with Redux and somewhat with Rxjs.

Comment: you are making your getOption call only one time right ???

Comment: you have used useEffect with [ ] dependency so it will always called once api call to setOptions, it may be the reason if parent component reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

A simple scenerio that i am thinking of is to not hit API when options are already loaded. You can do something like:

```
const Dropdown = ({ handleChange }) => {
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!options.length){
     //api call and setOptions
  }
}, []);

return (
  <Form.Dropdown name="abcd" label="abcd" options={options} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I think it doesn't solve my problem. The Dropdown component will be rendered multiple times. initially the options would be empty for every rendered dropdown, even if i move options state to redux and check for length, each components would still call the api since rendering is much faster than getting a response from api.

Comment: Then a solution is to lifting the state up, by saying so i mean to pass the options as a prop here from the parent component. And do the API call once in the parent component.